# Replacing multiplication by 2 with shift at runtime

Tags: optimization, runtime

I have integer data which is stored as a multiple of `k` of 1 (e.g., for *`k`=4*, if my data is *3*, then the actual data is *12*). In my program I read the data and need to convert it to the original value. The value `k` is always a power of two, but it is not known at compile time.

1. Can CPUs replace this muliplication at runtime with a shift operation?
2. Does it make a difference if the data is signed/unsigned integer?

I am working with an *x64* machine and *CUDA*, my program is written in *C++*, compiled with *gcc*.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you data is in the form `n * k` where `k = 2^i` and you want the CPU to automatically replace this by `n << i`? I am not sure why the CPU would even try to inspect a multiplication and check whether one of the operands is a power of two. However, since you know that it is, can't you use that fact in your code and write the shift directly?

Comment: @DanielJunglas Thats what I want to find out, whether I have to rewrite my multiplications to shifts or not. I try to follow the rule, not to pre-optimize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the cpu to perform the requested replacement, it will have to analyze the operands during dispatch. It will add a lot of complication for an uncertain efficiency since this type of replacement is done by the compiler for the constants ...
I don't know of any cpu that does this replacement.
If you are using an intel x86 you can get interesting information on https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-optimization-reference -manual.html